# can't i display two session message in one page

Tags: php, session

i have been displaying two session messages in one page, rating. One message is displayed in every refresh showing the likes and dislikes. the other message in displayed once the rating form is submitted, the problem is once i submit the rating form the message displaying the rating isn't displayed. why is so??? can't i use two sessions in a page?? thanks

coding

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['error_msg'])){?>
    <div style="text-align: center"><?php echo $_SESSION['error_msg'];?></div>

    <?
    session_unset($_SESSION['error_msg']);
}
?>

if(!empty($_SESSION['rate_msg'])){
            echo $_SESSION['rate_msg'];
            session_unset($_SESSION['rate_msg']);
        }
  ?>
  <form name="rating_form" action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="g_id" value="<?php echo $ratings['gallery_id'];?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="g_image" value="<?php echo $ratings['gallery_image'];?>"/>
      <div style="text-align: center">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Hot" onclick="document.rating_form.submit();">Hot</input>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Not" onclick="document.rating_form.submit();">Not</input>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: I think you mean two variables in a session. Is that so?

Comment: i mean two different session in one page from two different functions. one message is delivered only when i submit the form and the other rating message is displayed as x likes as y dislikes for the random pic generated on every refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is solved. of the two session message for the one i used php session while for the another one i used code igniter session. sorry if i haven't mentioned i am using ci. anyways thanks everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

sorry i think my code is a bit confusing
my actual code looks like this

```
<div class="top_model">
                    <h1>Model Ratings</h1>
                        <?php
                           if(!empty($_SESSION['error_msg'])){?>
                                <div style="text-align: center"><?php echo $_SESSION['error_msg'];?></div>

                                <?
                                session_unset($_SESSION['error_msg']);
                            }
                        ?>
                      <ul class="homemodel_thumbs">
                          <div style="text-align: right">

                              </div> 

                          <?php
                            if(!empty($ratingArr)){
                                foreach($ratingArr as $ratings){

?>

                          <li><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/gallery/large/<?php echo $ratings['gallery_image'];?>" alt="<?php echo $ratings['gallery_image'];?>" class="center_image"/>
                              <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                              <?php
                              if(!empty($_SESSION['rate_msg'])){
                                        echo $_SESSION['rate_msg'];
                                        //session_unset($_SESSION['rate_msg']);
                                    }
                              ?>
                              <form name="rating_form" action="" method="post">
                                  <input type="hidden" name="g_id" value="<?php echo $ratings['gallery_id'];?>"/>
                                  <input type="hidden" name="g_image" value="<?php echo $ratings['gallery_image'];?>"/>
                                  <div style="text-align: center">
                                      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Hot" onclick="document.rating_form.submit();">Hot</input>
                                      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Not" onclick="document.rating_form.submit();">Not</input>
                                  </div>
                              </form>

                          </li>    

                             <?php    
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                       </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're unsetting your rating message after you display it:

```
session_unset($_SESSION['rate_msg']);
```

This means it's not available after you've posted back the form unless you re-populate it again.

Remove this and i suspect it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You have an excess `?>` :

```
<?php
     if(!empty($_SESSION['error_msg'])){?>
        <div style="text-align: center"><?php echo $_SESSION['error_msg'];?></div>
<?
     session_unset($_SESSION['error_msg']);
     }

    if(!empty($_SESSION['rate_msg']))
    {
        echo $_SESSION['rate_msg'];
        session_unset($_SESSION['rate_msg']);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't open php tag for last statement, (or unnesesery close it) it's treated as html

```php
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['error_msg'])){?>
    <div style="text-align: center"><?php echo $_SESSION['error_msg'];?></div>

    <?php
    session_unset($_SESSION['error_msg']);
}
```

<strike>?></strike>

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['rate_msg'])){
            echo $_SESSION['rate_msg'];
            session_unset($_SESSION['rate_msg']);
        }
  ?>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php
// < HERE IS PHP >
if(!empty($_SESSION['error_msg'])){?>
    <div style="text-align: center"><?php echo $_SESSION['error_msg'];?></div>
    <!-- HERE IS HTML -->
    <?
    // < HERE IS PHP >
    session_unset($_SESSION['error_msg']);
}
?> <!-- CLOSED PHP - NOW IT'S HTML - YOU SHOULD REMOVE IT -->

<!-- THIS IS NOT EXECUTED - BECAUSE IT'S HTML NOW -->
if(!empty($_SESSION['rate_msg'])){
            echo $_SESSION['rate_msg'];
            session_unset($_SESSION['rate_msg']);
        }
  ?> <!-- THIS IS NOT PHP TAG BECASUE THERE IS NOT OPEN TAG -->
  <form name="rating_form" action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="g_id" value="<?php echo $ratings['gallery_id'];?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="g_image" value="<?php echo $ratings['gallery_image'];?>"/>
      <div style="text-align: center">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Hot" onclick="document.rating_form.submit();">Hot</input>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="Not" onclick="document.rating_form.submit();">Not</input>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: sorry i may have forgot to copy that tag but i have put php tag for last statement too. so no mistaking on that.

Comment: @samjhana then update your code. In your code, that you put, that closing tag is unnesesery, because last if statement is executed as html. You should see php code in your html source.

Comment: @samjhana If your code is correct then read the comment in your code that I put.